# How can I disable the Publish button in EPiServer's content editor?

Tags: episerver

I have an EPiServer project which is using the sequential workflow to validate content changes. This works fine, however we have a slight issue where content reviewers are just clicking Publish when they are happy with an editor's work. What they should be doing is using the workflow task window and indicating their approval through that.

To enforce this behaviour I would like to disable the Publish button in the content editor under certain circumstances (i.e. when there is an outstanding workflow task linked to the current page).

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this, or even an alternative solution to the problem altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you may want to revisit your workflow logic.

If a user with publishing rights publishes a page: that should be considered an approval. You could easily hook up to the Published event to see if the page is part of a currently running workflow.